# Validate if input number is in range from 1 to highest value given (for ex.. 100)

Tags: jsf

I've an input text field as below.

```
  <h:inputText value="#{student[column.property]}"  >
                   <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="#{marksdisplay.max_marks}" />
                </h:inputText>
```

I'd like to validate if the number is from 1 to 100 and show error otherwise. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-validatelongrange-example/

Comment: I need to change it without changing my id :(..

Comment: Why you can not use id?

Comment: because the id was created randomly... ther is no particular id

Comment: <h:inputText id="putHereYourDynamicId" value="#{user.age}"     size="10" required="true"     label="Age" >     <f:validateLongRange maximum="150" minimum="1" />    </h:inputText>    <h:message for="putHereYourDynamicId" style="color:red" />

Comment: you can use regular expression as well.

Comment: <h:inputText value="#{student[column.property]}" id="mark" required="true" requiredMessage="Value Out of Range" >
                       <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="#{marksdisplay.max_marks}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                 
                  <h:message for="mark" style="color:red" />

Comment: i have to change in this code

Comment: for ex... if the max_marks = 100; it does allow values only between 1-100...

Comment: yes, you have done correct.

Comment: but it does'nt show any effect.. it allows values over 100 also..

Comment: there is section as managed beam in the link i have provided you have u tried adding that as well

Comment: Are you saying that it also fails when you use `maximum="100"`?

Comment: yes... if i type 101.. it allows it..

Comment: So, you haven't declared `xmlns:f` taglib?